# Trying to understand ADC of STM32L4

Tags: arm, stm32, firmware, adc

I have difficulties understanding how STM32 ADC works.
I want to do something simple ie. sample and convert regularly ( @ 250Hz ) on 2 GPIOs. 
For now I did it in a "dummy" way: setup ADC in basic single mode, then launch a timer @250Hz and at each timer interrupt start the ADC to convert only one sample on each channel. But I don't think it is the right way to do and I'm worried about the lack of precision in terms of timing between samples.
Could you explain how I should configure the ADC to sample/convert continuously at a given frequency during a given number of samples ? I didn't find much usefull resources on the net and the reference manual is pretty complex.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular or Injected conversion sequences**

Each ADC can process two lists of channels to convert, a regular sequence with 16 channels (`SQR1`-`SQR4`), and an injected sequence with 4 channels (`JSQR`).

One of the main differences is that the regular conversion stores all results in a single shared data register (`DR`), which must be read out and stored before the next conversion step finishes. When there are more than one channels in a regular sequence, it's best to use DMA to store the conversion results. As you want something simple, I won't go into DMA now.

The injected conversion sequence stores each result in its own register (`JDR1`-`JDR4` or `JDR[4]`), then the software can read the results once the sequence finishes, which can be detected by polling the `JEOS` bit in the `ISR` register, or by enabling the interrupt with the `JEOSIE` bit in `IER`.

It is possible to start the injected sequence automatically when the regular sequence is finished (`JAUTO` bit in `CFGR`), that way it's possible to start 5 conversions in a row on each ADC unit, and have the results in different registers at the end.

**Starting conversion at regular intervals**

Instead of starting a conversion each time by software, you can set up a timer to start an ADC conversion sequence directly.

First, see the chapter titled *Conversion on external trigger and trigger polarity (EXTSEL, EXTEN, JEXTSEL, JEXTEN)* in the reference manual. There are lists of possible trigger events for regular and injected sequences. Pick a TRGO event from the table, set `EXTSEL` and `EXTEN`, or `JEXTSEL` and `JEXTEN` accordingly.

You might want to enable an end of sequence interrupt (`EOSIE` or `JEOSIE` in `IER`) now to notify the software when the sequence finishes.

Arm the ADC by setting `ADEN` and `ADSTART` or `JADSTART` in `CR1`, the conversion will start once the trigger from the timer arrives.

Program the timer that you selected from the table above for the desired frequency, and set the `MMS` bits in `CR2` to `010` (Update). Each overflow (update) of the timer will generate a trigger event, starting the next ADC conversion sequence. It's not necessary to enable the timer interrupt.

**Using more ADC units**

If there are more than one ADC units in your controller, you can start them simultaneously using the same trigger on each one. This way you can do 2 or 3 conversions at the exact same time, or start up to 15 conversions and have the results at once without using DMA.

Comment: I've implemented what you suggested (thank you very much for your time BTW) and it works fine except for one thing. I have setup TIM15 as trigger for ADC. I had already tested the setup of this timer and it is counting at the right frequency : when I launch the timer alone, I get timer UIF interupt at the right frequency, as expected. I am able to trigger the ADC sampling sequence but the sampling rate (ie. the rate at which I get ADC IRQ) is twice slower than the timer update frequency ( I have only one channel).

Comment: In other words I get an ADC EOS interrupt only one out of 2 timer updates. The timer update occurs every 5seconds so it's not a problem of ADC sampling being longer than timer update.

Comment: Will ask a separate question on this issue.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Do it. Post the code, otherwise it'd be hard to guess what went wrong.